# Extract email and name with regex

Tags: regex, language-agnostic

What would be the regular expressions to extract the name and email from strings like these?

```
johndoe@example.com
John <johndoe@example.com>
John Doe <johndoe@example.com>
"John Doe" <johndoe@example.com>
```

It can be assumed that the email is valid. The name will be separated by the email by a single space, and might be quoted.

The expected results are:

```
johndoe@example.com
Name: nil
Email: johndoe@example.com

John <johndoe@example.com>
Name: John
Email: johndoe@example.com

John Doe <johndoe@example.com>
Name: John Doe
Email: johndoe@example.com

"John Doe" <johndoe@example.com>
Name: John Doe
Email: johndoe@example.com
```

This is my progress so far:

```
(("?(.*)"?)\s)?(<?(.*@.*)>?)
```

(which can be tested here: http://regexr.com/?337i5)

Comment: What all possiblities of valid email are you having? Note that regex for validating all the emails may be vast. You need to clarify what all emails are you considering as correct.

Comment: I don't need to validate the email.

Comment: Which language or tool are you using this in?

Comment: @RohitJain Works for me in different browsers. In any case, I added my current best regex.

Comment: @m.buettner I prefer to keep it language agnostic.

Comment: You really want to be finding a library which parses emails for you, for whatever language you happen to be using. Regexes do exist to parse each and every possible value for an email, but they are very much insane.

Comment: @fge I don't why that is needed here. I can assume the email is valid, and that it will either be alone, or between <>.

Comment: @hpique regexes simply aren't language agnostic

Comment: @m.buettner True. But the various implementations are similar enough to discuss this question without worrying about their differences. :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The following regex appears to work on all inputs and uses only two capturing groups:

```
(?:"?([^"]*)"?\s)?(?:<?(.+@[^>]+)>?)
```

http://regex101.com/r/dR8hL3

Thanks to @RohitJain and @burning_LEGION for introducing the idea of non-capturing groups and character exclusion respectively.

Comment: There's an unnecessary non-capturing group. Simply `(?:"?([^"]*)"?\s)?<?(.+@[^>]+)>?` produces the same result

Answer (score 1):

use this regex `"?([^"]*)"?\s*([^\s]+@.+)`

group 1 contains name

group 2 contains email

Answer (score 1):

```
(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))
```

https://regex101.com/r/pVV5TI/1

Comment: this seems to accept "test <test@xample.com" (without the final >)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this (same code as yours but improved), but you need to check returned groups after matching because the email is either returned in group 2 or group 3, depending on whether a name is given.

```
(?:("?(?:.*)"?)\s)?<(.*@.*)>|(.*@.*)
```

Comment: Is there no way to keep it in the same capturing group?

Comment: @hpique: Depends on your language and regex flavor. It can be done using the `(?|...)` construct if that is supported, otherwise perhaps making the `<` and `>` optional. If validation is required, this can be done using conditional statements or any other clever construct :-).

Answer (score 0):

This way you can get with or without name, removing the quotes.

```
\"*?(([\p{L}0-9-_ ]+)\"?)*?\b\ *<?([a-z0-9-_\.]+@[a-z0-9-_\.]+\.[a-z]+)>?
```

Answer (score 0):

Although @hpique has a good answer, that solution only works when the name/email string is the only thing being analyzed in Regex. It will not work when you have a longer message that contains other items, such as an email. Also many of the other solutions will fail to match when the person has included a middle name (i.e. James Herbert Bond <jbond@example.com).

Here is a more robust Regex solution I wrote that can pick up the first names, last names, and emails like you wanted, even if there are many other things in the string:

```
/(?:"?)(\b[A-Z][a-z]+\b ?)(\b[A-Z][a-z]+\b ?)*(?:"?) ?<([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)>|([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/g
```

Check out the above syntax here: [Example on Regexr](https://regexr.com/5pg37)

Comment: this doesn't seem to accept "tom <test@example.com>" (only finds the email within the angle brackets. Should it be requiring capitalization because "Tom <test@example.com>" seems to work.