# Extract name and email from string in JS

Tags: javascript, regex, email

How can I extract the name and email from a string, where emails are separated by commas.

The [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14010875/4548321) below works great for individual emails, but not for emails within a string.

```
(?:"?([^"]*)"?\s)?(?:<?(.+@[^>]+)>?)
```

**Note** the *comma* within the name as well.

```
johndoe@baidu.com, John <johndoe@google.com>, John D, A <johndoe@bing.com>, "John Doe , Yen" <johndoe@163.com>
```

Output:

```
Name: null
Email: johndoe@baidu.com

Name: John
Email: johndoe@google.com

Name: John D, A
Email: johndoe@bing.com

Name: John Doe , Yen
Email: johndoe@163.com
```

Comment: What's the output that you expect?

Comment: Also had a try, [see fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y5yvuu90/) :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to tell if the data will change or remain the same, but here's my attempt:

```
var re  = /(?:"?([A-Z][^<"]+)"?\s*)?<?([^>\s,]+)/g;

while (m = re.exec(str)) {
  if(m[1]) { m[1] = m[1].trim() }
  console.log("Name: "  + m[1]);
  console.log("Email: " + m[2]);
}
```

[**Working Demo**](https://eval.in/282070)

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possible answer:

```
(?:^|, *)(?![^",]+")(?:((?=[^"<]+@)|(?![^"<]+@)"?(?<name>[^"<]*)"? *))<?(?<email>[^,>]*)>?
```

This is using ruby regexes, and uses forward matches to determine if an entry has a name.

1. `(?:^|, *)`: start at the front of the string, or after a , and a number of spaces
2. `(?![^",]+")`: negative lookahead, abort match if there are some characters and then a `"`. This stops commas from starting matches inside strings.
3. `(?:((?=[^"<]+@)|(?![^"<]+@)"?(?<name>[^"<]*)"? *))`: matching the name:

   1. `(?=[^"<]+@)` if a @ occurs before a quote or open brace, it is just a email address without name, so do no match
   2. `(?![^"<]+@)"?(?<name>[^"<]*)"? *)`: otherwise, match the name (skipping the open and close quote if they are present
4. `<?(?<email>[^,>]*)>?`: match the email.

[On rubular](http://rubular.com/r/UKhodvxEH6)

Note that for a real job, this would be a terrible approach. The regex is near incomprehensible, not to mention fragile. It also isn't complete, eg what happens if you can escape quotes inside the name?

I would write a dedicated parser for this if you really need it. If you are just trying to extract some data though, the regex may be good enough.