# Strip contact information from email

Tags: javascript, regex

I sometimes have users enter emails like:

`John Smith <john@example.org>`

I have a regex like `/(.+[ <>])/g` but this is not correct for this.

I would like to have an output like:

`john@example.org`

I only want the email component, and want to ignore anything else a user may give.

Edit: People are getting confused. I simply want the input to turn out like the output. This has nothing to do with validation. I already have validation. This has to do with cleaning the input before it even gets to the validation.

Comment: Please elaborate on your question. It's not clear exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: @CD.. I am not trying to validate an email. Did you read the question?

Comment: @spectacularbob The email address entered was being hidden, I have put it in code tags it should make more sense now.

Comment: I suggest leveraging a parser.  How about [this to get started](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/207-ask-ben-extracting-parts-of-an-email-address-in-javascript.htm) (especially the comments)?

Comment: @bishop I have an input like `John Smith <john@example.org>` and I want to strip anything that isn't the email. So that string should become `john@example.org`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Extract name and email from string in JS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28421327/extract-name-and-email-from-string-in-js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming an e-mail for your input always has an "@" symbol, you can select the single token your e-mail makes with the symbols you'd like to accept.
For example:

`[A-Za-z0-9.]*?@[A-Za-z0-9.]*`

```
test test test john smith@hotmail.com test
```

will result in

```
smith@hotmail.com
```

E-mails can contain dashes and underscores (`john-smith@hotmail.com`), so consider adding them into the `[A-Za-z0-9.]` character class, making it `[A-Za-z0-9.\-_]`, or whatever characters you feel are appropriate.

Comment: Thanks, this is the kind of thing I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this will work, though you may want to modify it a little according to which characters you want to allow in an email address

```
<(\w+@[a-zA-Z_]+?\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3})>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$/
```

Answer (score 0):

One-liner:

```
var str = "John Smith <john@example.org>",
mail = /[^<>]+/g.exec(/<.+>/g.exec(str))[0];
```