# ASP Classic extract email address from string

Tags: asp-classic

I need to be able to pull an email address from a string in ASP Classic.

Example string is "Please Contact Cp. from XXXX located in xxxx with regards to enquiry details - Hi, I am writing to you to cancel Thank you . Chris Pearson email address : chris@itsanemail.com.au phone number : 07 56431545 Preferred contact method : Email"
With the result being "chris@itsanemail.com.au"

note that the email wont always be in the same location within the string. there will however always be spaces either side.

i can do this in excel without issue, but cant find a script to do this. it doesn't have to be perfect. happy if it picks up the majority

Comment: There's a question on Experts Exchange with deals with this. https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/26886544/VBSCRIPT-EXTRACT-EMAIL-ADDRESS-FROM-TEXT-FILE.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract email and name with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14010875/extract-email-and-name-with-regex)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Function GetEmailAddrFromStr(TheString)
    If InStr(1,TheString,"@") > 0 Then
        TheAt = InStr(1,TheString,"@")
        StartMarker = InstrRev(TheString, " ", TheAt, 0)
        EndMarker = InStr(TheAt,TheString," ")
        GetEmailAddrFromStr = Trim(Mid(TheString,StartMarker,EndMarker-StartMarker))
    Else
        GetEmailAddrFromStr = ""
    End If
End Function

SomeText = "Hi, I am writing to you to cancel Thank you . Chris Pearson email address : chris@itsanemail.com.au phone number : 07 56431545 Preferred contact method : Email"

Response.write GetEmailAddrFromStr(SomeText)
```